# Why when I apply DataFrame.sub() I get the new DF with a higher number of columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, methods

I can't understand `Pandas` behaviour when I apply `.sub()` method in this specific situation where my goal is to center the rows in the `DataFrame`.

Basically I want to compute for each row the mean value and then subtract this value from each row in order to get the `DataFrame` centered.

I think the issue is related probably to the element-wise operation, but remains quite obscure the reason also after reading the documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sub.html)

```
import pandas as pd
val = {1: [1,2,3,4],
       2: [4,5,6,7],
       3: [8,9,10,11],
       4: [12,13,14,15]}

df = pd.DataFrame(val)
# Computing for each row the mean value
avg = df.mean(axis=1)
#Removing the mean value from each element in each row
df_centered = df.sub(avg,axis=1)

print(df)
print(avg)
print(df_centered)


   1  2   3   4
0  1  4   8  12
1  2  5   9  13
2  3  6  10  14
3  4  7  11  15
0    6.25
1    7.25
2    8.25
3    9.25
dtype: float64
    0     1     2     3   4
0 NaN -6.25 -4.25 -1.25 NaN
1 NaN -5.25 -3.25 -0.25 NaN
2 NaN -4.25 -2.25  0.75 NaN
3 NaN -3.25 -1.25  1.75 NaN
```

1. I can't understand why I get this output
2. I would like that my output is a 4X4 not a 4X5, why I have a 5th column?
3. Why I get `NaN` from the operation?

### Edit

**Expected output:**

```
 df_centered
         1      2      3      4
    0 -5.25  -2.25    1.75   5.75
    1 -5.25  -2.25    1.75   5.75
    2 -5.25  -2.25    1.75   5.75
    3 -5.25  -2.25    1.75   5.75
```

I think the fact that all the rows are equal is just specific for this example.

Now If you calculate the mean for each row from `df_centered` it will be `0`, as expected from a "centering" process.

Comment: Ciao Andrea, do you mind to add your expected output?

Comment: Hi @rpanai added, sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer for all your questions are in this part of documentation:

```
For Series input, axis to match Series index on.
```

In your case your columns are `print(df.columns)`:

```sh
Int64Index([1, 2, 3, 4], dtype='int64')
```

while `print(avg)`:

```sh
0    6.25
1    7.25
2    8.25
3    9.25
dtype: float64
```

so here indices are `0, 1, 2, 3`.

According to the piece of doc above you need to add an extra columns `0` to `df`, in the same way there is no index `4` in `avg` so you are doing subtraction with NaN and the results is NaN.

A way to overcome this is to rename indices in `avg` with

```py
avg.index = df.columns
```

But, as far as I can see, using `level=0` or `level=1` yield the same result.

I guess that there are some problems with the way it broadcast the operation. So I'd suggest you the following solution.

## Data

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import pandas as pd

val = {1: [1,2,3,4],
       2: [4,5,6,7],
       3: [8,9,10,11],
       4: [12,13,14,15]}

df = pd.DataFrame(val)
```

## Generate matrix to subtract

We first ask the result to be a numpy array

```py
avg = df.mean(axis=1).values
```

Then we repeat for the number of row in `df`

```py
rep = np.repeat(avg, len(df))
```

And finally we reshape it according to `df`

```py
mat = rep.reshape(df.shape)
```

```sh
[[6.25 6.25 6.25 6.25]
 [7.25 7.25 7.25 7.25]
 [8.25 8.25 8.25 8.25]
 [9.25 9.25 9.25 9.25]]
```

Now `df.sub` works as expected

```py
df_centered = df.sub(mat)
```

which is the dataframe you are looking for

```sh
      1     2     3     4
0 -5.25 -2.25  1.75  5.75
1 -5.25 -2.25  1.75  5.75
2 -5.25 -2.25  1.75  5.75
3 -5.25 -2.25  1.75  5.75
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `axis=0` in [`DataFrame.sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sub.html) for subtract pre rows, it means `6.25` is subtracted by first row of DataFrame:

```
df_centered = df.sub(avg,axis=0)
print(df_centered)
      1     2     3     4
0 -5.25 -2.25  1.75  5.75
1 -5.25 -2.25  1.75  5.75
2 -5.25 -2.25  1.75  5.75
3 -5.25 -2.25  1.75  5.75
```

> Why I get NaN from the operation?

Because indices of columns `0,5` are different like indices of index of `Series` `avg`, here `1,2,3,4`, so pandas not matching and missing columns are created.

Comment: @rpanai - For me working perfectly, your solution is overcomplicated in my opinion.

Comment: Which pandas version are you using? My solution is made to avoid to deal with pandas broadcasting.

Comment: I was wrong. It works fine. Maybe I did mistake before. Anyway I upvoted your answer ;)